# In AWS Tried connecting rds from ec2 both are in same vpc(not default vpc) getting error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Tried connecting an Amazon RDS database to an EC2 instasnce. Both are in new VPC getting this error:

```
 Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have 1 public subnet for EC2 and 2 private subnets for database, created subnet group and security groups.

RDS security group tried with below inbound rules:

```
option: 1
PostgreSQL  TCP 5432    0.0.0.0/0                               Traffic from EC2
All traffic All All sg-0706b9fb2d2c2dbce / public-sc-eks-demo   Public Subnet SC

option: 2
PostgreSQL  TCP 5432    <ec2 ip address>                    Traffic from EC2
All traffic All All sg-0706b9fb2d2c2dbce / public-sc-eks-demo   Public Subnet SC
```

Do we need outbound rules for EC2 security group?

Comment: I wonder why the error message is saying `Is the server running locally`? How are you connecting to the database? What connection details are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have:

- An Amazon EC2 instance in the same VPC as an Amazon Redshift database
- You wish to connect to the Redshift database from the EC2 instance

From security standpoint, you should have two security groups:

- One **security group on the Amazon EC2 instance** (`EC2-SG`) with sufficient Inbound rules for you to be able to login, and default Outbound rules that Allow All traffic, *and*
- One **security group on the Amazon RDS instance** (`DB-SG`) that permits Inbound access on port 5432 from `EC2-SG`

That is, the `DB-SG` should specifically reference `EC2-SG` in the Inbound rules.